# Kurtosis of Poisson

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

I'm trying to show that the kurtosis if *X* is $3+\lambda^{-1}$ for a Poisson.

I think I should start by calculating the fourth moment around the mean and then at some point rewrite it in terms of first or second moments. I know the first moment is lambda, and the second moment around the mean is lambda, but am not able to get anywhere from there that's clear.

Comment: Why are you not calculating $\displaystyle \sum_{k=0}^\infty (k-\lambda)^4\frac{\lambda^ke^{-\lambda}}{k!}$ and then dividing by the square of the variance?

Comment: Henry, yes that's what I should be doing. I can't figure out how to simplify it to get a coherent answer...

Comment: Did you mean that the second moment around the mean is $\lambda$?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. Editing it now.

Comment: A trick that might help you to "get a coherent answer" is that, for every nonnegative integer $n$, $$\sum_{k=0}^\infty k(k-1)\cdots(k-n+1)\frac{\lambda^ke^{-\lambda}}{k!}=\sum_{k=n}^\infty \frac{\lambda^ke^{-\lambda}}{(k-n)!}=\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{\lambda^{k+n}e^{-\lambda}}{k!}=\lambda^n.$$

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to solve this is through the use of the poisson distribution's moment generating function. The $k$th moment of a distribution it the $k$th derivative of its moment generating function evaluated at $0$. The $mgf$ for a poisson is as such $M_x(t) = e^{u(e^t-1)}$ where u is the mean of the poisson distribution. The $4$th central moment can be expanded into a polynomial function of the moments of $X$.